# android-json-rpc unable to resolve static field 253 (VERSION_2)

Tags: android, json-rpc

I try to call a JSONRPC webservice with android-json-rpc library, but my Eclipse logCat throw this warning:

```
W/dalvikvm(344): VFY: unable to resolve static field 253 (VERSION_2) in Lorg/alexd/jsonrpc/JSONRPCClient$Versions;
```

This warning appears when I try to create the client:

```
JSONRPCClient.create (URL, JSONRPCClient.Versions.VERSION_2);
```

Consequently it can not create JSONRPCClient.

Answer (score 3):

Change

This

```
JSONRPCClient.create (URL, JSONRPCClient.Versions.VERSION_2);
```

With

```
JSONRPCClient.create (URL, JSONRPCParams.Versions.VERSION_2);
```

In this way if you have enabled android permission INTERNET in the manifest, the command should works.

Comment: I tried with JSONRPCClient.create (URL, JSONRPCClient.Versions.VERSION_2); in 0.31 version. Also I tried JSONRPCClient.create (URL, JSONRPCParams.Versions.VERSION_2); with 0.32 and 0.33 versions, but it throws same warning. And yes, I enabled android permission INTERNET in the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You must use;

```
JSONRPCClient.create (URL, JSONRPCParams.Versions.VERSION_2);
```

And sometimes, Eclipse keep warnings and errors. Try to do: Project -> Clean.

Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds potentially similar to a problem I had.  Is the library getting exported with the APK?  Maybe try the steps listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14131270/513038.