# How to solve these logcat warning messages ??? Android Studio

Tags: android

I am receiving these warning messages and I not sure how to fix:

> 02-14 14:01:15.255: I/dalvikvm(10677): Could not find method
>   android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.255: W/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 11769: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted
>   (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.255: D/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at
>   0x0000
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.255: I/dalvikvm(10677): Could not find method
>   android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.255: W/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 11775: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll
>   (Landroid/view/View;)V
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.255: D/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at
>   0x0000
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.260: I/dalvikvm(10677): Could not find method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.260: W/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 9420:
>   Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll
>   ()V
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.260: D/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x000e
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.605: I/dalvikvm(10677): Could not find method
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.605: W/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 547: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations
>   ()I
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.605: D/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0002
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.610: I/dalvikvm(10677): Could not find method
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.610: W/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 569: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
>
> 02-14 14:01:15.610: D/dalvikvm(10677): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0002

My Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bkbarbados.com.mygcm" >

    <!-- Permissions for GCM -->
    <permission
        android:name="bkbarbados.com.mygcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="bkbarbados.com.mygcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:name=".Global"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ListPeople"
            android:label=" Chat App">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:label=" Chat App"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
        </activity>

        <!-- Receiver for GCM -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="bkbarbados.com.mygcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The library you added is not checked in build path. Try this link

[Unable to solve virtual method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543653/vfy-unable-to-resolve-virtual-method)

Comment: Which library are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

It can get quite involved to repair.  A previous discussion on the problem:

[What do these Android logcat warnings mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065249/what-do-these-android-logcat-warnings-mean)